# About swift's calendar schedule registration logic

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

It is a question.

An error "index out of range" will occur on line 73(CellForRowAt of TableView).
However, I think that values ​​are included in "events", but why is this?

In addition, it is a question.
I can not question the logic by all means.

I am planning to implement a calendar now, and I use FSCalendar as a library.
The simple calendar is completed and the event registered as the next step (ex, event ⇨ "prefectural convention", "start date" ⇨ "October 1", "end date" ⇨ "October 10") I'd like to display it in the UITableView placed on the bottom side of the calendar.

However, I do not understand the logic before coding and I am in trouble because I do not come out even if I examine it.

The database uses CloudFireStore, and as a structure,

> date_end: "September 23, 2018",
>
> date_start: "September 27, 2018",
>
> event_title: "Match in Takaragai-ike",
>
> scheduleID: "6F4YLHAcwZ3GuSS81sGK",
>
> time_end: "10: 00",
>
> time_start: "16: 00",

Has become.

I would like you to tell me whether there is logic that can break through or that the database structure itself is wrong.
Also, if you do not know the meaning, I would like to tell you.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FSCalendar
import CalculateCalendarLogic

struct DisplayEvent {
    var event: String
}

class scheduleViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
  @IBOutlet weak var pickedDate: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let db = Firestore.firestore()

  var events = [DisplayEvent]()

  var fireAuthUID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "no data")

  var teamIDFromFirebase: String = String()

  var timeIntervalArray: [String] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      calendar.dataSource = self
      calendar.delegate = self
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self

      tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ScheduleTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "scheduleCell")

      currentDate(pickedDate)

      beginAlert()
  }

  fileprivate let gregorian: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
  fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy年MM月dd日"
      return formatter
  }()


  @IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
      calendar.setCurrentPage(getNextMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
  }

  @IBAction  func previousTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
      calendar.setCurrentPage(getPreviousMonth(date: calendar.currentPage), animated: true)
  }

  @IBAction func TapApp(_ sender: Any) {
      let eventShare = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "planController") as! planController
      self.present(eventShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}





extension scheduleViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleTableViewCell
      let hogeCell = DisplayEvent(event: events[indexPath.row] as! String).event

      cell.commonInit(schedule: hogeCell)
      return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return 70
    }
}


extension scheduleViewController: FSCalendarDelegate,FSCalendarDataSource,FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition){
      let selectDay = getDay(date)
      pickedDate.text = "\(String(selectDay.1))月\(String(selectDay.2))日\(String(selectDay.3))曜日"
      let scheduleForDate = "\(String(selectDay.0))年\(String(selectDay.1))月\(String(selectDay.2))日"
      getScheduleDate(date: scheduleForDate)
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func judgeHoliday(_ date : Date) -> Bool {
      let tmpCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

      let year = tmpCalendar.component(.year, from: date)
      let month = tmpCalendar.component(.month, from: date)
      let day = tmpCalendar.component(.day, from: date)

      let holiday = CalculateCalendarLogic()
      return holiday.judgeJapaneseHoliday(year: year, month: month, day: day)
    }

    func getDay(_ date:Date) -> (Int,Int,Int,String){
      let tmpCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      let Component = tmpCalendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
      let weekName = Component - 1
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")

      let year = tmpCalendar.component(.year, from: date)
      let month = tmpCalendar.component(.month, from: date)
      let day = tmpCalendar.component(.day, from: date)

      return (year,month,day,formatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[weekName])
    }

    func getWeekIdx(_ date: Date) -> Int{
      let tmpCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
      return tmpCalendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

      if self.judgeHoliday(date){
          return UIColor.red
      }

      let weekday = self.getWeekIdx(date)
      if weekday == 1 {
          return UIColor.red

      }
      else if weekday == 7 {
          return UIColor.blue
      }

      return nil
    }

    func getNextMonth(date:Date)->Date {
      return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to:date)!
    }

    func getPreviousMonth(date:Date)->Date {
      return  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to:date)!
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
      let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
      return 0
    }

}


private extension scheduleViewController {

    func currentDate(_ currentTet: UILabel) {
      let currentPickedDate = getDay(Date())
      currentTet.text = "\(String(currentPickedDate.1))月\(String(currentPickedDate.2))日\(String(currentPickedDate.3))曜日"
    }

    func beginAlert() {
      let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "ようこそ！", message: "マイページでチームIDを確認しよう！", preferredStyle:  UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
      let defaultAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{
        (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("OK")
      })
      alert.addAction(defaultAction)
      present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func generateTimeRange(date: String) -> [String]? {
      var result: [String] = []
      guard var startTime = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }
      guard let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }

      while startTime <= endTime {
          result.append(dateFormatter.string(from: startTime))
          startTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startTime)!
      }
      return result
    }

    func getScheduleDate(date: Any) {

      var startTimeArrForStart = [Any]()
      var endTimeArrForStart = [Any]()
      var scheduleArrForStart = [Any]()


self.db.collection("users").document(fireAuthUID).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
          guard let document = snapshot else {
              print("erorr2 \(String(describing: error))")
              return
          }
          guard let data = document.data() else { return }
          self.teamIDFromFirebase = data["teamID"] as? String ?? ""
          self.db
              .collection("teams")
              .document(self.teamIDFromFirebase)
              .collection("schedule")
              .whereField("date_start", isEqualTo: date)
              .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
              if err != nil {
                  print("scheduleを取得できませんでした")
                  return
              } else {
                  for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                      guard let dataFromFirebase: [String : Any] = document.data() else { return }
                      let startTimeFromFirebase = dataFromFirebase["date_start"] ?? ""
                      let endTimeFromFirebase = dataFromFirebase["date_end"] ?? ""
                      let scheduleFromFirebase = dataFromFirebase["event_title"] ?? ""
                      startTimeArrForStart.append(startTimeFromFirebase)
                      endTimeArrForStart.append(endTimeFromFirebase)
                      self.events.append(DisplayEvent(event: scheduleFromFirebase as! String))
                      self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```